model.find(filters) not working in mongoose
I am trying to fetch listings in  single country using mongoose .find(filters) s such:
const listings = await Listing.find({
            countryForInvestmemt: country,
            status: "Published"
});

However, it just returns all the listing without filtering them
the country parameter is working fine

Please share more information, maybe add your model or data samples. There is little context here.

@AmiraliAmirifar what other information do you need? everything else has been tested and is working just fine

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
